# I need help, even t in my account i can't buy individually because my family sharing keeps asking for Credit Card of the manager!

Tags: apple-id, appletv, sharing, family-sharing

I want to rent movie worth $4.99, and i have $7.39 but it still asks me for Credit Card security code from manager!

Answer (score 1):

This would occur if the credit card the family manager set up was declined the last time it was tried, and/or there is a balance owing to Apple for a prior purchase that did not go through. In any case, the family manager will have to resolve the issue.